# Stable/Unstable Manifold Theorem for a Morse-Bott function

Tags: morse-theory

Good night, anyone know of any reference where I can find the proof of the **Stable/Unstable Manifold Theorem for a Morse-Bott function**. I'm interested in the dimensions of the stable and unstable manifolds, these dimensions are intuitive but wanted to know of some reference.

Thank you very much, all references will help me.

Comment: "Lectures on Morse theory, old and new" by Raoul Bott himself (http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1982-07-02/S0273-0979-1982-15038-8/) is a must, although there are not too many details about this particular point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper *Morse-Bott theory and equivariant cohomology* by D. M. Austin and P. J. Braam (in The Floer memorial volume, Progr. Math., 133, 1995) is a good reference for Morse-Bott theory. In particular Proposition 3.2 and Theorem A.9 seem to contain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The most general sort of theorem along those lines can be found in the book Invariant Manifolds by Hirsch, Pugh, and Shub, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics Volume 583.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember (I don't have the book at hand right now to check), the book *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* by Lawrence Perko (Springer, 1991) has a version of the stable manifold theorem for the case that some eigenvalues of the linearization of your vector field have zero real part.